# Finding an arbitrary pair of sets $U,V$ that is a separation of $A \in X$ and will satisfy $U \cap V \cap (X - A) \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Say I have some topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X = \lbrace a,b,c \rbrace$ and a disconnected subset $A \subset X$.

Can it be true that any arbitrary pair of sets - say $U$ and $V$ - that is a separation of $A \in X$ will satisfy $U \cap V \cap (X - A) \neq \emptyset$ ?

I have the definition of separation as: Let $T=(X,τ)$ be a topological space and let $A, B$ be open sets of $T$.

$A$ and $B$ form a separation of $T$ iff:

1. $A$ and $B$ are non-empty
2. $A∪B=X$
3. $A∩B=∅$

If we look at the second condition and think of $U$ and $V$ as $A$ and $B$, then we know $A \cap B = \emptyset$ because they are disjoint. Hence we run into the issue that adding more intersections can only reduce the total elements in the new set. We're starting with the empty set, so I'm not seeing $U \cap V \cap (X - A) \neq \emptyset$

I must be either missing a definition or misreading some of this.

Can anyone think of an example where this would be the case? If I can visualize it, it might be easier to prove.

Comment: This condition is clearly false when $A=X$ is disconnected. Because $X-A=\emptyset$ and thus so is the intersection. For proper $A\subset X$ you can take discrete topology as a counterexample, and $A$ any subset with at least two elements.

Comment: More generally, if $U, V$ are a separation, then by the definition $U\cap V = \emptyset$, And the intersection of the empty set with any set is still going to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $U$ and $V$ form a separation then $U\cap V=\emptyset$, and so $U\cap V\cap (X - A) = \emptyset$.